Given a simple planar graph, can one triangulate it in such a way that the simplicity is preserved?
I feel like this should be obvious, but I can't find it anywhere. Given a planar graph $G$, one can triangulate it by adding edges between vertices bounding cycles of length $\geq 4$. This is fair enough -- however, the resulting triangulation need not be simple. For example, consider a cycle of length exactly $4$ with a chord between opposite vertices $u$ and $v$. The outer face is bounded by $4$ vertices. In trying to triangulate this graph, we might add another edge joining $u$ and $v$ on the exterior of the cycle, creating parallel edges. As such, I would like to ask:

Given a simple planar graph, can one always triangulate it in such a way that the simplicity is preserved?


A triangulation that is not simple is not a triangulation. The interest in triangulations is that they are precisely the maximal planar graphs, which only makes sense if by "graph" we mean "simple graph"; there is no maximal planar multigraph, because we can keep adding edges forever. Any textbook on graph theory should prove the claim you want, but I would state it as "Every planar graph has a triangulation" and with this formulation, it might not be clear that everything is assumed to be simple!

Call a simple plane graph $G$ maximally plane if there is no simple graph $G'$ on the same vertex set, with $E(G')\supsetneq E(G)$. It is a well known result (see for instance Diestel's Graph Theory, chapter 4) that a simple plane graph $G$ is maximally plane if and only if it is a plane triangulation (all faces are triangles).

Thanks for clearing up my misunderstanding! I believe the exact proposition is 4.2.6 in Diestel.

No problem. That sounds right, though the exact number might depend on the edition.
